# Trying to get related entities from H2 database in Java Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I've just started learning Spring Boot and am using a H2 database, I've got mostly everything working but I'm running into trouble trying to make a slightly more complex request. I've got 2 tables 'User' and 'Purchase', and I want to create and end point that returns all purchases that contain a given users ID. This seems simple if I used an SQL join or some similar query but I have no idea how to implement one.

I have a repository (CrudRepository) for both user and purchases, and then a service for each that gets the relevant data from database. This works perfect for the basic needs such as get, getById, etc. But I have no idea how to specify queries such as join and what not.

```
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {}

public interface ReceiptRepo extends CrudRepository<Receipt, Integer> {}

@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepo userRepo;
 
    public User getUser(int id) { return userRepo.findById(id).get(); }
}

@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/user/{id}")
    private User getUser(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        return userService.getUser(id);
    }
}
```

That's basically the set up for both entities, and I'm not sure where and how I'd write more specific queries. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoy can use @Query() annotation in order to write query.
You need to declare a method in your repo and on that method you can put this annotation.

Eg:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.status = 1")
Collection<User> findAllActiveUsers();
```

You can take some more idea about this from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)

Comment: Ahh okay I get you, if I defined the query in the repo how would I pass the id to it. For example, if the request body contained the id in question how would I get the id to the repo method

Comment: @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.status = ?1")
User findUserByStatus(Integer status);
 
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.status = ?1 and u.name = ?2")
User findUserByStatusAndName(Integer status, String name);

Comment: you can check the link, you get all about it there